# How many mortal sins did/does Satan do?

Tags: catholicism, sin, angels, mortal-sin

How many mortal sins did/does Satan do? Did Satan commit just one mortal sin? Does the number of mortal sins increase as he tempts people to commit sin? I am interested in the Catholic viewpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How many mortal sins did/does Satan do? Did Satan commit just one mortal sin?*

Satan lost sanctifying grace by committing the sin of pride alone (not envy,  disobedience, or any other sin; cf. Hugon, O.P., [*Tractatus Dogmatici* vol. 1](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=7205) p. 693, PDF p. 353).

Suárez's [*De angelis*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=7653) lib. 7 cap. 15 (p[p. 897](https://archive.org/details/rpfranciscisuare02suar/page/897/mode/2up)-910) goes into much depth regarding the question of "Whether, besides pride, Lucifer committed other sins *in via*" and whether these were "by diverse acts or by diverse ill-wills of the same [act]."

---

> *Does the number of mortal sins increase as he tempts people to commit sin?*

cf. [*Summa Theologica* I q. 63 a. 2](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP063.html#FPQ63A2THEP1) "Whether only the sin of pride and envy can exist in an angel?" co.:

> omnia peccata in Dæmonibus esse contingit, quia dum homines ad omnia peccata inducunt, omnium peccatorum reatum incurrunt.
>
> <sup>all sins are in the demons; since by leading men to sin they incur the guilt of all sins.</sup>

Comment: Does his punishment in hell increase as he incurs more sins (via tempting humans)?

Comment: @Thom [Demons' wills are obstinate in the evil chosen](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP064.html#FPQ64A2THEP1), so how could they will more or less evil and incur more or less punishment?

Comment: cf. Maldonado (commenting on [Mt. 8:29](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=8&l=29-#x), quoted on PDF p. 210n14 of [_Sacræ Theologiæ Summa_ IIB](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=7426)): "The opinion must be held that the Church has already recognized, namely, that even now the demons are tormented and wherever they go...they take their punishments along with them; but that they are punished less now because they have the power to roam about the world and to harm men."